# Facebook - retrieve user info using ID

Tags: facebook

In my database I have facebook ID-s of users of my App.
Now I need to retrieve these users in PHP.
I use this:

```
$json=file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/UID");
$fdata=json_decode($json);
$fname=$fdata->name;

echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['uid'].'/picture">';
echo '$fname';
```

I need to put this code into WHILE.. I already retrieve users photos using UID, but I also need names. As I understand I should write something Like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



  $json=file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/$row['uid']");
      $fdata=json_decode($json);
      $fname=$fdata->name;



 echo $row['uid'];

 echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$row['uid'].'/picture">';

 echo "<br>";


  }
```

But it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _“But it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong??”_ – well, your first error is assuming “doesn’t work” is a valid error description. And then, you’re doing _nothing, nada, zilch_ with the data you try to get from the API – so what result are you expecting …?

Comment: You don't appear to be using anything taht you get from the JSON call. you don't use $fname, for instance. What are you trying to do, even?

Answer (score 0):

Use the official PHP SDK for Facebook.
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/src

Then call:

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => <app_id>,
  'secret' => <app_secret>,
  'cookie' => true
));
```

Then use the api, like:

```
$varfordata = $fb->api();
```

A good site for searching: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/